# Why do I get the wrong results with my smart bot logic in this Game of Nim program?

Tags: java

The game of Nim. Two players alternately take marbles from a pile. In each move, a player chooses how many marbles to take. The player must take at least one but at most half of the marbles. The player who takes the last marble loses. The program is played between the computer(bot) and human. The strategy to win is to select a number such that `(2^n)-1` is remaining in the pile.
Size is selected randomly between `10` and `100`.

In smart mode, the bot is supposed to select enough marbles such that there are `(2^n)-1` remaining in the stack(e.x 3,7,15,31,63..). Except when there are exactly `(2^n)-1` marbles already remaining in the stack, in which case the bot selects random no. of `marbles < (size/2)`. Instead I'm getting the following output:

```
Total no. of marbles = 96
Your turn to pick: 
8
Remaining marbles: 88
Bot has selected:4
Remaining marbles:84
Your turn to pick: 
34
Remaining marbles: 50
Bot has selected:12
Remaining marbles:36  and so on..
```

Code:

```
int i;
int op=0;   //op becomes 1 when size=(2^n)-1
for(i=2;((2^i)-1)<=size;i++){   //size is total remaining marbles
  if((2^i-1)==size){
      if((size%2)==0){
           sel = rand.nextInt(size/2)+1; //sel is selected no. of marbles
      }
      else{
            sel = rand.nextInt((size-1)/2)+1;
      }
          size = size - sel;
          op =1;
      }
      if(((2^i)-1)<size){
           sel = (2^i)-1;  //in this case sel is required remaining marbles
             op =0;
         }
      }
       if(op==0){
             System.out.println("Bot has selected:"+(size-sel));
             size = sel;
             System.out.println("Remaining marbles:"+size);
       }
       else{
            System.out.println("Bot has selected:"+sel);
            System.out.println("Remaining marbles:"+size);
       }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I don't get the logic behind this strategy, what are the rules for this game variant.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Also, as noted by @Henry, you should explain the rules of the Nim game, or at least provide a wikipedia link.

Comment: **The game of Nim**. Two players alternately take marbles from a pile. In each move, a player chooses how many marbles to take. The player must take at least one but at most half of the marbles. The player who takes the last marble loses. The program is played between the computer(bot) and human. The strategy to win is to select a number such that '(2^n)-1' is remaining in the pile.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to find what is the bigger number n smaller than size so that n = (2^i-1). This number is - in binary - a sequence of "1" so you can use a smart way to find it. As you find it, and you discover that your original number is a sequence of "1", then you must get instead a random number not bigger than half of the remaining stones. So, this is the function that determines how many stones bot must remove:

```
public int stonesToRemove(int size) {
    if (size<=1) 
       return 0; // to avoid exceptions
    int toremove = size;
    int j = 0;
    while (size > 1) {
        j = 1 | j << 1; // this means j=j*2+1
        size >>= 1; // this means size=size/2
    }
    if (toremove == 1+(j << 1)) {
        toremove = 1+new Random().nextInt(j);
    } else {
        toremove -= j;
    }
}
```

You don't need such big iteration, just a little method like that.